# How to implement a page which displays all methods available with an ASP.NET Web API OData Service?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm hoping to implement an ASP.net Web API REST service to wrap complex object types and make them available via the OData protocol to compliment our existing WCF Data Service projects which easily expose database tables from an Entity Model.

What is the easiest way to provide a list of all available 'methods' on the Web API Service which is view-able from the browser? (Basically to replicate what WCF Data Services does OOTB when you navigate to the .svc page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to look at the ApiExplorer class.

There is a recent tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-help-page-for-a-web-api).

There should be a help page in the project templates in the next release [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/10/31/asp-net-web-api-help-page-is-now-part-of-the-web-api-project-template.aspx).

Until then there is a Nuget version [here](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage).

Answer (score 3):

You can access the $metadata url i.e '~/$metadata' to get this information.

Comment: This is part of the OData spec but is not provided OOTB by ASP.NET MVC4 Web Api projects as far as I can tell